# how to get Ascii values of 2 letters with excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out the largest revision of a document using an excel formula (only). The revision can be numbers, single letters (A, B, C, etc), or double letters (AA, AB, AC, etc)

I converted the column to "text" so that I can get ASCII values of numbers and single letters, but how do I get an ASCII value of AA?

I used the =code() function to convert letters and numbers to an ascii code, and use "maxifs" to get the largest number. The order of revisions are 1, 2,3.....A,B,C....AA,AB,AC and so on. AA gives me the same Ascii value as A, so this is my problem. AA is higher than Z, and so on.

Note: maxif of numbers gives me the lowest rev - which is wrong, but not critical.

[image]

Comment: Please include some actual sample data in the form of markdown syntax in your question. Add which value is largest and how you want to get the output.

Comment: Does technically the ascii value of `AA` is `130` ERickG

Answer (score 2):

How about this (using Office 365):

```
=@LET(rev,DROP(TOCOL(A:A,1),1),
      SORT(HSTACK(rev,+ISERR(--rev),LEN(rev)),{2,3,1},-1))
```

This sorts all data in column A (excluding header) by:

1. String being number/text
2. String length
3. Revision's first character code

This is sorted in descending order.

By adding `@` in front of the formula, it returns the first value of the sorted array result, which is the largest listed Rev.

See below a screenshot of the sorted array without using `@` showing the largest rev in the first cell of the spill array.

[image]

Note that I didn't use the ASCII code because in your example it appears that for instance `11` is smaller than `A`. Using that logic `999` would also be smaller than `A`.
This formula copes with that.

It returns the max Rev without translating it to a (ASCII) value representation of the data.

Answer (score 2):

If the idea is to obtain a numerical equivalent for sorting purposes, and your data is as you describe: numbers or single or double capital letters, and the letter revisions will be higher than the numeric revisions, then you could use the following formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,COLUMN(INDIRECT(A1&"1"))+100)
```

The `100` factor at the end just needs to be larger than the largest numeric revision.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For one character you can use the code function, for example:

```
=code("a")
```

will give you 97

But you ask a good question- how can one print in the same cell more than one value?
The answer will be the '&' sign, so if you type:

```
=code("a")&code("b")
```

You will get 9798.

Notify that it can print more than one value, so if you need spaces you can type:

```
=code("a")&" "&code("b")
```

so you will receive 97 98
and so on....

Comment: that wouldn't work since my letters are together and not in separate cells. if I had A and B in separate cells, I could do that, but I have AA, AB, and so on!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=SUMPRODUCT(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)))
```

It's kind of a clumsy method using the "INDIRECT" function, but it works.

Comment: Clumsy-but works!! TY

Answer (score 0):

Yet another suggestion for sorting:

```
=IFERROR(--A1,DECIMAL(A1,36)*100)
```

If not a decimal number, the string is regarded as a number in base 36 where A represents 10 and Z represents 35.

[image]

So to find the last revision, if you have Excel 365:

```
=@LET(data,TOCOL(A:A,1),SORTBY(data,IFERROR(--data,DECIMAL(data,36)*100),-1))
```